# Django 2.0 User_Auth -> best practice to check if Username and Email exists

Tags: python, django, authentication

At my Django project Email and Username must be unique.

I want to check if they exists, but Django **User model** don't provide me the method like

`.filter()`, `.count()` or `.exists()` unfortunately. ( I don't know why.)

[django.contrib.auth - User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user)

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username= request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
        user.save()
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
    else:
        """Return template with sign up page."""
        return render(request, "account/account_signup.html")
```

I want to check in this below way, because I need separate the HTTP Response Code.

```
if User.objects.filter(username=username).count() > 0:
    return HttpResponse(status=401)

if User.objects.filter(email=email).count() > 0:
    return HttpResponse(status=402)
```

I know, that Django raise me the error when I try create existing username:

```
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username
```

But I want to check it in views layer. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found beauty answer: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django User model manager has the same methods as other models. So you can check for existing username or email using this for example (similar to your code, but using `.exists()`, to avoid count operation).

```
if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
    return HttpResponse(status=401)
```

Comment: It's not true. When I try use .filter() or .exits() method I get an error.